# How to count cells that only contain the VALUE 0 and not the result of a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, countif

For the following sheet:

```
    A
1   0
2   0 as formula result
3   0
4   0 as formula result
5   0 as formula result
6   blank
7   0
```

How do I count only the cells with `0` entered as VALUES and not the cells with `0` as their formula result, i.e.

`COUNTIF(A1:A7,0 AS VALUE)` = 3

I've tried the following:

`COUNTIF(A1:A7,0)` = 6

`COUNTIF(A1:A7,"0")` = 6

Comment: Just a note that in Excel 2013, you could do something with the `FORMULATEXT` function, which returns `#N/A` if there's no formula.

Comment: what if the formula result is blank? +1 or leave that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about Excel, but VBA has this functionality. So you can define a small UDF to achieve this:

```
Function HasFormula(r as Range) As Boolean
    HasForumla = r.HasFormula
End Function
```

Now you can call this function with IF and COUNT to get your results.

Answer (score 9):

COUNTIF(A1:A7;0)
this worked for me

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA-defined function will count the number of cells in a range that have zeros.

```
Function CountZeros(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    CountZeros = 0
    For Each cell In rng
        If (cell = 0) And (IsEmpty(cell) = False) And Not (HasFormula(cell)) Then
            CountZeros = CountZeros + 1
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill cell `B1` with this formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1=0,ISFORMULA(A1)=FALSE),1,0)
```

Copy this formula to cells `B2:B7`

sum cell `B1:B7` and you get what you want.